# Transistor logic to drive h-bridge with negative voltage source

Tags: transistors, mosfet, digital-logic, h-bridge, negative-voltage

Shown below is a H-Bridge circuit I have used to drive the cathode of a VFD display with a source voltage of +2.4V with a +3.3V digital logic level.

[image: Original H-Bridge Circuit]
I have decided to switch the cathode source voltage to -2.4V from the +2.4V in order to increase efficiency elsewhere in the system. Obviously this presents problems with the simplicity of driving the H-Bridge, which is unfortunate because I'm terrible at figuring out transistor logic.

How would the H-bridge driver have to be adapted if the source cathode voltage was -2.4V, but the digital logic controlling it was still +3.3V?

Thanks.

EDIT:
The N-channel MOSFETS are BSS138. The P-channel are BSS84.
The 3.3V digital logic interface is connected directly to a PIC16F.

Comment: What are the part numbers of your FETs?

Comment: What  are your interface specs for V and skew time? Is this ECL to TTL?

Comment: I've added the part numbers for the FETs in an edit. As for the skew time, I wouldn't think it'd be relevant because this is a very very slow H-bridge, but I may be wrong. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "V". The control interface (connected to the FET gates) is driven directly by a PIC16F microcontroller, if that helps?

Comment: If you just switch the voltage in the upper part of the schematics to -2.4V, the two PMOS will be always OFF (VGS>=0V)